# how to handle imepadding when textfield is at bottom of view in jetpack compose?

Tags: keyboard, focus, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, padding

When the basictextfield is at bottom of view and is focused, the basictextfield is moving to the center of screen. How can I stop that? If I remove imePadding(), only half of textfield is visible.

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            var a by remember {
                mutableStateOf("")
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .imePadding()
            ) {
                BasicTextField(
                    value = a, onValueChange = { a = it }, modifier = Modifier.align(
                        Alignment.BottomCenter
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```